# parameter as a drop down list

Tags: ms-access

I am very new to access and would like to have users select report criteria from a drop down list of clients before running the report.  The Client names can be lengthy, so asking users to type for parameters will not work.  I have built most of my function with macros and am intimidated by the code builder.  Anyone willing to help a beginner?

Comment: When you say "access", do you mean Microsoft Access?

Comment: Yes, I do mean Microsoft Access

Comment: How about telling us.. more about the scripting language, the platform.. is it a game? is it a website? What is it really? (because no one can understand at all what you are talking about from reading that story of yours. Sorry)

Comment: Sounds to me like the original questioner is just trying to build an app in Access (hence the mention of "macros"). I don't really see a question here, other than "can anyone provide links to tutorials/recommendations for books on beginning Access application development".

Answer (score 2):

The task is:
**You have some report that needs to display data filtered by user selected value(s) on the form**
The screenshot below (MS Access 2007) shows the basic setup for this scenario:

[image]

Please not this simple solution **does not** require any VBA code.

Below are the key components:

1. Form's drop-down:
   [image]
2. Macro setup:
   [image]
3. Report. Please note the RecordSource is just Clients table (no WHERE
   clause etc.):
   [image]